# How can the GitHub REST API retrieve project custom issue fields?

Tags: github-api

In the GitHub UI, the Settings for a project allow adding custom issue fields specific to that project. Looking at a specific issue within that project displays those fields and allows you to change them.

I have not yet found anything in the GitHub REST API documentation about retrieving custom fields, let alone modifying them. What am I overlooking?